# Track Recipints and message from Facebook send dialogue

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Our e-commerce portal is providing a referral program. When a customer recommends a product to 5 friends in facebook he will be getting 10% discount on that product.

Facebook "Send Dialog" is used to refer to a friend in facebook.

```
FB.ui(
  {
       method: 'send',
       link: data.producturl
  },
  function(response){
       if (response && !response.error_code) {
             console.log("OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
       } else {
             console.log("Not OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
       }
  });
```

The response for "send dialog" is not providing any information.

I am trying to get following data

```
1) Count of recipients
2) Recipient name/ID
3) Message sent
```

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to reward users for sending private messages. Please go read [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, FB does not allow and there's no technical way to retrieve the recipients' details.

My suggestion to you is to add a parameter a parameter at the end of the link (data.producturl) that will indicate the affiliate_id and on the landing page to generate a unique ID on page load and save it in the LocalStorage. This way, as long as the user hasn't deleted his localStorage (most users don't even know what it is), you'll be able to check if they already visited and link, so you won't credit the affiliate twice.